# Canadian Visitor Visa for indian parents to attend graduation while study permit is expired and work permit in process

Tags: visas, canada

My son is graduating in November and I want to apply for the visitor visa for my family to attend it. While his studies will be done by the end of August (study permit expires then) and work permit will be under process, can we apply for our visitor visas explaining this to the embassy right now? If not, is the alternative to wait for the work permit? If so, we will be traveling to the United States in September to visit my daughter, can we apply for the Canadian visitor visa from there? Which would be the better option?